# Resource Scheduling in Arena Simulation Software

Tags: model, simulation, data-modeling, simulator, arena-simulation

I have a big problem in a simulation model. Entities arrive before and wait until 6.00 AM. And entities arrive after 6:00 AM, don't get any problems and walk inside. How does one model this in Rockwell Arena?

Answer (score 1):

[This course's site](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~sman/courses/6644/) contains some examples and lecture notes that might be helpful for Arena. Specifically, [this lecture covers scheduling resources](http://www.isye.gatech.edu/~sman/courses/6644/KSS03_Chapter%2004.pdf) in Arena which start on slide 30.

Your best bet is to do some Google searching. A lot of class notes/lectures and possibly some examples show up:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=arena+resource+schedule
- https://www.google.com/search?q=arena+resource+schedule+filetype:ppt
- https://www.google.com/search?q=arena+resource+schedule+filetype:pdf

Finally, [here is the full blown reference guide for Arena (pdf)](http://literature.rockwellautomation.com/idc/groups/literature/documents/um/arenab-um001_-en-p.pdf). I think more official documentation can be found here:

http://literature.rockwellautomation.com/idc/groups/public/documents/webassets/browse_category.hcst

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak specifically to Arena, but in most discrete simulation engines tasks have a field where you can define criteria for a task to start.  In your case, you wouldn't allow a task to start until 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "based on schedule" element in the create module. Then at the schedule data module you can enter the arrival rates that is zero until 6 AM. However, if you are implying that you must also take into consideration the entities that arrived but waited until 6 AM then taken into process; you can possibly use a dummy create module that handles those arrivals that arrive before 6AM and terminate it at 6AM and then take that number as a extra arrival in your original system.